# Paypal live issue Non US

Tags: paypal

When I was setting the paypal application I see this note:

> Important: Live credentials are disabled for some capabilities. We
>   require additional information from you for these capabilities as
>   noted below.

And this:

> Accept PayPal and allow direct credit card processing Non U.S.
>   developers, please note that direct credit card processing is not
>   offered to you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are
>   inoperable for direct credit card processing but your test credentials
>   are enabled for sandbox testing.

What I understand of this is that a Non U.S. account could no process Direct Credicard payments, but they don't say anything about others payment capabilities.

So I made my application, use the REST API in Sandbox and everything works great.

No I was setting the live application and I couldn't. After reading again the Documentation I found this:

> Do I need a U.S. PayPal account to sign up? To accept payments using
>   the new REST APIs and PayPal Mobile SDK, we currently require a U.S.
>   PayPal Business account. But stay tuned for more country support. Note
>   that most countries can use our Classic APIs.

Some is very confuse the message, **Am I or Am I not able to use an UK business account to process payments (with for example paypal balance) with the REST API?**

Answer (score 1):

The REST API is currently only available to US merchants. UK merchants cannot yet use the feature - sorry.

From the FAQ page on Developer.PayPal.com:

```
Do I need a U.S. PayPal account to sign up?

To accept payments using the new REST APIs and PayPal Mobile SDK, we currently require a U.S. PayPal Business account. But stay tuned for more country support. Note that most countries can use our Classic APIs.
```

Comment: Any Update with Classing API's and mobile iOS SDK of Paypal?